# How to sort a list by item valie in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, sorting, move

Is it possible in VueJs to display my blocks sorted by "block.position" value, and update all block position when I click on a "UP" or "DOWN" button?

I want to have my blocks in correct order in my "blocks" array, reflect the index position on the "block.position" value, and display all my blocks in a correct order.

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <div class="mb-5" v-for="(block, index) in blocks" :key="block.id">
    
                <div class="btn btn-primary" @click="move(index,index-1)" v-if="index">
                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="btn btn-primary"
                     @click="move(index,index+1)" v-if="index !== (blocks.length - 1)">
                    <span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
                </div>
    
                <h3 class="text-uppercase text-info"><u>{{ block.name }}</u> - {{ block.position }}</h3>
    
                <div v-for="field in block.fields" :key="field.id">
                    <p>{{ field.name }}</p>
    
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div v-if="field.type === 'textarea'">
                            <textarea
                                :required="field.required"
                                :placeholder="field.attr ? field.attr.placeholder : null"
                                :value="field.data"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div v-else>
                            <input
                                :type="field.type"
                                :required="field.required"
                                :placeholder="field.attr ? field.attr.placeholder : null"
                                :value="field.data"
                            />
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" v-for="error in field.errors">
                            {{ error }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="border-light">
            </div>
    
            <ul class="list-unstyled d-block">
                <li class="d-inline-block">
                    <button class="btn btn-light" v-on:click="addParagraph">
                        Add Paragraph
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li class="d-inline-block ml-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-light" v-on:click="addImage">
                        Add Image
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
    
        </div>
    
    </template>
    
    <script>
    // Going to use this neat array function
    Array.prototype.move = function (from, to) {
        this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);
        return this;
    };
    
    export default {
        name: 'BlockForm',
        created() {
            // Tri dans le tableau les blocks par "block.position".
            this.updateBlockPosition();
        },
        data() {
            return {
                blocks: [
                    {
                        id: 0,
                        type: 'paragraph',
                        name: 'Paragraphe',
                        position: '1',
                        fields: [
                            {
                                id: 0,
                                type: 'textarea',
                                name: 'Saisissez votre texte ci-dessous',
                                required: true,
                                data: null,
                                errors: [
                                    'Lorem ipsum sir dolor emet',
                                ],
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        type: 'image',
                        name: 'Image',
                        position: '2',
                        fields: [
                            {
                                id: 0,
                                type: 'file',
                                name: 'Sélectionner une image',
                                required: false,
                                placeholder: null,
                                data: null,
                                errors: [],
                            },
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                type: 'text',
                                name: 'Description de l\'image',
                                required: false,
                                placeholder: null,
                                data: null,
                                errors: [],
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        type: 'image',
                        name: 'Image',
                        position: '3',
                        fields: [
                            {
                                id: 0,
                                type: 'file',
                                name: 'Sélectionner une image',
                                required: false,
                                placeholder: null,
                                data: null,
                                errors: [],
                            },
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                type: 'text',
                                name: 'Description de l\'image',
                                required: false,
                                placeholder: null,
                                data: null,
                                errors: [],
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            };
        },
        methods: {
            addParagraph() {
                this.blocks.push({ ...this.blocks[0] });
                this.updateBlockPosition();
            },
            addImage() {
                this.blocks.push(this.blocks[1]);
                this.updateBlockPosition();
            },
            move(from, to) {
                this.blocks.move(from, to);
                this.updateBlockPosition();
            },
            updateBlockPosition() {
                this.blocks.forEach((block, index) => {
                    block.id = index + 1;
                    block.position = index + 1;
                });
            },
        },
    };
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: seems  like u need a sort method in between the click event and the rerendering ur blocks.

like every time u click ur event button it goes trough a sort algo. and then displayes the order u want in updateBlockPosition

Comment: Try to move create a kind of a `getter` in `computed` section that will return your array. In the move method reorder your array as well. Doing so will trigger your list to update. I have almost similar implementation but i am just using tables instead of custom made list.